# Не отображается язык

Tags: java, android, локализация, локаль

Проблема следующая. На одних устройствах язык (Телугу) отображается (планшет Prestigio, samsung 6,  в том числе на эмуляторах Genymotion), на другом устройстве нет (Alcatel One Touch, android 4.2.2). Причем в последнем устройстве длина невидимого текста определяется, текст место занимает, в лог (Android Studio) выводится.

Вывожу поддерживаемые устройством языки следующим образом -

```
for (Locale locale : Locale.getAvailableLocales()) {
        Log.i("LOCALE", locale.getLanguage() + "_" + locale.getCountry() + " [" + locale.getDisplayName() + "]");
    }
```

Отстуствие языка "te" (Telugu) в этом списке не мешает отображению на экране, кроме Alcatel.

Как я понимаю проблема может всплыть не только в Alcatel-моделях, хотелось бы разобраться в причинах. В какую сторону глядеть, на что обратить внимание, что еще добавить к вопросу для ясности?

Интересно,можно ли программно определить, что шрифт не отображается, но длину/размер строки в представлении имеет?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вероятно, стандартный шрифт Алкателей не содержит нужных символов. Попробуйте включить в ваше приложение шрифт, который точно будет работать, и устанавливать его для отдельных представлений

```
someTextView.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/myfont.ttf"));
```

или для всего макета

```
public class FontChangeCrawler {
    private Typeface typeface;

    public FontChangeCrawler(Typeface typeface) {
        this.typeface = typeface;
    }

    public FontChangeCrawler(AssetManager assets, String assetsFontFileName) {
        typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(assets, assetsFontFileName);
    }

    public void replaceFonts(ViewGroup viewTree) {
        View child;
        for (int i = 0; i < viewTree.getChildCount(); ++i) {
            child = viewTree.getChildAt(i);
            if (child instanceof ViewGroup) {
                replaceFonts((ViewGroup)child);
            }
            else if (child instanceof TextView) {
                ((TextView) child).setTypeface(typeface);
            }
        }
    }
}

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    public void setContentView(View view) {
        super.setContentView(view);

        FontChangeCrawler fontChanger = new FontChangeCrawler(getAssets(), "fonts/myfont.otf");
        fontChanger.replaceFonts((ViewGroup)this.findViewById(android.R.id.content));
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за отклик. Интересно,можно ли программно определить, что шрифт не отображается, но длину/размер строки в представлении имеет?

Comment: Нет, не думаю, что это возможно.